# Trigger next submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having problem with selecting the next submit button via jQuery.

I have something like this:

```js
$('.description-part').on('change', 'textarea', function() {
  $(this).find('.button').addClass('test'); // not working
  $(this).next('.button').addClass('test'); // not working
  $(this).closest('.button').addClass('test'); // not working
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="description-part">
  ...
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div></div>
  <input type="submit" name="save" class="button">
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `nextAll()` as the `this` is `textarea` and not `div` and you have a `<div>` in between the `textarea` and `button`, so `.next()` won't work either:

```
$('.description-part').on('change', 'textarea', function() {
    $(this).nextAll('.button').addClass('test');
});
```

Or you can use `.closest()` this way:

```
$('.description-part').on('change', 'textarea', function() {
    $(this).closest('.description-part').find('.button').addClass('test');
});
```

**Working Snippet**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.description-part').on('change', 'textarea', function() {
    $(this).closest('.description-part').find('.button').addClass('test');
  });
});
```

```css
.test {background: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="description-part">
  ...
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div></div>
  <input type="submit" name="save" class="button" />...
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.description-part').on('change', 'textarea', function() {
    $(this).nextAll('.button').addClass('test');
  });
});
```

```css
.test {background: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="description-part">
  ...
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div></div>
  <input type="submit" name="save" class="button" />...
</div>
```